# Ansible -How to Compare two files between source and destination file and append the content from source to destination file

Tags: ansible

I have two files called source.txt and destination.txt as below,
**Source.txt**

```
[profile appdev]
Arn: aaa.dev:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile applead]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile appprod]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile apppadmin]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile appsupport]
Arn: aaa.dev:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
```

**destination.txt**

```
[profile appdev]
Arn: aaa.dev:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile applead]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile appprod]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
[profile apppadmin]
Arn: aaa.techlead:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
```

When we compare source.txt and destination.txt, the below content is missing,

```
[profile appsupport]
Arn: aaa.dev:333:iam
Region: ap.southeast2
```

I want to append the missing content to destination.txt else we can skip it if no difference.
I have used diif command in shell module, but i am  not getting proper difference

Any idea how to do it in Ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you always want to have the same content on the 2 files if there is a difference, usually, I do that using the copy module:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Copy content of file src to destination
    copy:
      src: /home/myfolder/txt2.txt
      dest: /home/myfolder/txt1.txt
    check_mode: yes
    diff: yes
```

(You can delete check_mode see the link to know why: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html Basically check mode is a simulation and wont change any file)

Comment: Thanks for promot response ,Once i have deleted check_mode and the missing content is append but i have added another profile in middle of source file, no changes in destination file

Comment: You are welcome, its a very fast example I did, but I think its useful, if you can mark it as a correct answer will be great :)